# Почему результат NaN? Должна вычислить общую стоимость товара и вернуть её

Tags: javascript

```js
let sum;

function calculateTotal(name, price, amount) {
  let obj = {
    name: name,
    price: price,
    amount: amount
  }
  sum += price * amount;
  return sum;
}

let result = calculateTotal('food', 350, 5);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Если сложить undefined и число - что должно получиться? Присвойте значение переменной sum `let sum = 0;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что у тебя `sum` инициализирован `undefined`. Надо его инициализировать нулём